# designing a game so adding internet multiplayer wont change core implementation

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hey I'm Building a small UI based game of tic-tact-toe.

it is currently local play, but i will want to add an online mode in the future.
what should i consider when building core functionality, so adding the online mode won't force me to change the implementation of the core game ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you play tic-tac-toe as a single player? Aren't there always two players? ;)

Comment: Sorry i meant not through the internet :)
i'll edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By implementing a client-server model from the start.

This means, regardless of local or play over the internet you'd always run a server in the backend.

At the start, you spin up a local server. This has the core of the gameplay. The 'Game' then is nothing more than a simple viewer application which acts as a client and calls the server api for any game logic.

Popular games like minecraft do the same. When starting multiplayer, a local server is used and when playing online, the local server is simply changed by a remote server.

Comment: Thank your, do you have any recommendation for guides or tutorials on how to do it ?
(i know there are tons, but i mean ones you think are good)

Comment: Not specifically for unity no. But this question is really the same as 'how do i build a multiplayer game' because that's what you'll be doing. There are tons of good tutorials out there and i'd just pick something that resonates with you the most. Personally i like Jason weimann for this kind of stuff. He can go on an on, but he is very thorough and shows all aspects of game design (in the coding sense) which i like. Check out his livestream for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2so32ZlMoU